# Falling into issues Trying to Create a Program Derived Address (PDA) with Solana-py: "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)"

Tags: python, solana

```
    params = system_program.CreateAccountWithSeedParams(
    base_pubkey = keypair.public_key,
    from_pubkey = keypair.public_key,
    lamports = 200,
    new_account_pubkey = greeted,
    program_id = program_id,
    seed = 'hello',
    space = 8
)
```

I am Getting the output

> CreateAccountWithSeedParams(from_pubkey=2ASw3tjK5bSxQxFEMsM6J3DnBozNh7drVErSwc7AtzJv, new_account_pubkey=BkuEamVXuHugbAAVurExanW1FGAejsEAa7hECYsP1j6o, base_pubkey=2ASw3tjK5bSxQxFEMsM6J3DnBozNh7drVErSwc7AtzJv, seed='hello', lamports=200, space=8, program_id=TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)

The problem then comes when I use

`transaction_Params = system_program.create_account_with_seed(params)`

I get the long slew of errors, whose long story cut short is: **not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)**

and full story: [image: full Story]

Any Help will be more than Cherished and Appreciated, but will also get a significant amount of Thankful cheers

Comment: Welcome to SO, don't use screenshots to share code or tracebacks - this is difficult for folks to read.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the `seed` provided should actually be a dict that serializes directly to a Rust string.  Here's a test that does it: https://github.com/michaelhly/solana-py/blob/b507d4dfe16cdaccc754b1f2bac5ed9e258ea039/tests/unit/test_system_program.py#L64

Separately, if you're trying to create a program-derived address, you'll actually need to create it from within a program, using `invoke_signed` in your program.  It is not possible to create a program-derived address from the outside, because you need the program to "sign" for the program-derived address.  See the differences between https://solanacookbook.com/recipes/accounts.html#program-derived-address and https://solanacookbook.com/recipes/accounts.html#create-account-with-seed

Comment: In this situation, Why am I required to find_program_address with thesame seed as that which I used in params, In which case, I will be generating an address that does not lie on the ed25519 curve, which to me only seems like a PDA.

BTW, the seed format works as a dict, Thank you, What I don't know is how to make the seed uniform across find_program_address and create_account_with_seed, cause we are inputting a dict vs a bytearray

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't totally clear.  You can generate the *address* off-chain in your client code, but if you want to create an account at that address, you'll need to pass in the seeds so that the runtime can verify the program-derived address.  To be honest, don't worry about `create_account_with_seed` at all, there are very few situations where you'll need it.

Comment: ok, Thanks. Much appreciated.